# Removing CompilerOptions directive for an interop

Tags: asp.net, interop, rcw

I've created an interop for a COM dll via `tlbimp` and added it to the assembly cache. To use this in an ASP.net page i need to include the following

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" CompilerOptions='/R:"C:\Program Files\blah\blah\LIBRARY.dll"'%>
<%@ Import Namespace=LIBRARY %>
```

Why do i need the CompilerOptions directive if it's in the assembly cache? Can i simplify and centralize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add a reference just as you would add any other assembly reference. That's all /R: does.

EDIT: If you're not explicitly building the web app elsewhere, using /R in the aspx file is probably your best bet. The reason you need it is that ASP.NET is effectively building the application for you, and *something* needs to tell it which library to reference, even if that library is in the GAC. It's just like normal assembly references in a Visual Studio project - if you remove a reference to `System.Xml`, you won't be able to use the XML classes even though that assembly's in the GAC.

Comment: Thanks Jon, i'm not using Visual Studio. How can i do this in VB or C# code only? I've tried "Import LIBRARY" and LIBRARY is in the assembly cache and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the additional clarification Jon.